# python logging.Formatter adding additional values to message

Tags: python

I've created a method that logs to my syslog server and am using 'logging.Formatter' to format the message.  However, it seems that `Formatter` is adding additional text to my syslog message and I am unsure of how to get rid of it.

Here's the method located in `logger.py`:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os

def sendLog(msg):
    address = "192.168.1.200"
    port = 514

    syslogger = logging.getLogger("app_processing LEVEL='{}'".format(os.environ['ENV']))
    syslogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # f = ContextFilter()
    # syslogger.addFilter(f)

    handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=(address, port))
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s", datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    syslogger.addHandler(handler)
    syslogger.debug(msg)
```

And I'm calling it from other modules with:

```
logger.sendLog("FUNCTION='get_inventory_db' MESSAGE='Retrieving inventory information'")
```

Yet, when it's logged to the server the result is:

```
2017-10-20 14:48:35 -04:00 192.168.1.101 192.168.1.101 user.debug 10/20/2017  18:48:35 app_processing LEVEL='development' FUNCTION='get_inventory_db' MESSAGE='Retrieving inventory information'
```

Note the `2017-10-20 14:48:35 -04:00 192.168.1.101 192.168.1.101 user.debug` that shows before what should be the start of the syslog message.

I'm expecting output like:

```
10/20/2017  18:48:35 app_processing LEVEL='development' FUNCTION='get_inventory_db' MESSAGE='Retrieving inventory information'
```

Am I not using the Formatter correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You do everything completely correct with the formatters & logging library.

The mentioned prefix has nothing to do with the python's logging library. The whole line starting with `"10/20/2017  18:48:35 ………"` is being sent by python to the syslog.

Whatever is added on top of that, is the syslog's configuration, and should be investigated there, on the syslog's server side. It cannot be controlled from the app and its logging.

The only way you can "fix" these lines is by removing any datetimes from your own log formats, and rely on the syslog's proper prefix.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know... I'll approach it from the other side.